# How to search stack Overflow (The search results are better in 'Ask Question')

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, search

I always find myself in this situation:

1. I have a programming question.
2. I navigate to the search bar and search for it.
3. I do not find a good answer.
4. I go to "Ask Question".
5. I type in the title to my question.
6. The "Questions that may already have your answer" populates many useful results!!
7. I cancel my question and carry on...

Anyone else have that happen?? Am I not using the search bar correctly? I swear I type in the same things...

Comment: Use google. It's far better at indexing for natural language questions than the SO search engine seems to be. The SO search engine, in turn, can do queries on tags, types of posts, specific users, etc. So, choose your appropriate tool for the task at hand. =)